# Camphor for molecular mass determination

Tags: colligative-properties

I came across this statement in my book that read, "Camphor is used to determine the molecular mass of substances because it has a high value of cryoscopic constant." What does this have to do anything with the ease of determining molecular masses?
I am not familiar with the process that is being referred to, and hence, do not understand the significance of camphor having a high cryoscopic constant. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't the quoted statement answer the question? Also, please always provide *complete references* for the sources you quote.

Comment: Is the question more on what the cryoscoic constant is, or how it helps if camphor has a high value?

Comment: Related: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/7/jresv7n3p477_A2b.pdf

Comment: @JonCuster Its more on how it helps if camphor has a high value

Answer (score 2):

Following [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryoscopic_constant) freezing point depression can be used to determine molecular masses as the freezing point depression depends on the number of particles (a colligative property).

In an experiment, you would dissolve a known mass of the unknown sample in a known mass of a solvent (here camphor) and compare the change in freezing point for sample-camphor mixture to pure camphor. Some worked examples can be found at [chemteam](https://www.chemteam.info/Solutions/FP-depression.html)

This effect is much larger for camphor than for many other (more common) solvents.